# Visual Basic .net, create reference to an object

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a simple application. It has 2 listboxes, but both lists are mostly the same. So in my code, I want to be able to execute the same code on either listbox easily.

In VB6, I could name both controls the same, assign an index to them, and that works. Here in VB.net 2008, it seems to not be possible.

What I ideally want, is to create a variable during the program that I can assign to either of the listbox, and then during the rest of the code use this new variable to control the listbox attached to it.

Here's an example:

```
Private Sub lVegetables_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lVegetables.Click
    ListToEditor(0, lVegetables.SelectedIndex)

End Sub


Private Sub lFruits_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lFruits.Click
    ListToEditor(1, lFruits.SelectedIndex)
End Sub

Private Sub ListToEditor(ByVal iList, ByVal iIndex)

    Select Case iList
        Case 0
            Dim lList As lVegetables
        Case 1
            Dim lList as lFruits
    End Select

    tEditor.text = iList.item(iIndex)



End Sub
```

Is there a way I can use a different variable to reference to a listbox on the fly, or can I assign an index to them so they have the same name?

Comment: Your code has quite a few errors in. What's wrong with passing the list itself instead of a magic number index?

Comment: Create a variable with form level scope of the appropriate type but those seem to be 2 different types.  You should set `Option Strict On` especially if you are going to play with global variables

Comment: You certainly can have a variable which references another object.  I guess it's not clear to me from the code provided specifically what you're trying to do.  Shouldn't the parameters in `ListToEditor` have types?  What is `Dim lList As lVegetables` doing?  You're just declaring a variable, not using it for anything.  And is `lVegetables` really a type, or is it a variable?  It's just not clear to me what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I am trying to create lList variable that references to an actual listbox. But if I can simply pass the object itself, then that's a good solution too.

Comment: But if they are both listboxes, you are never going to know which one it is set to.  you could easily perform a veggie action on a fruit.  Generally, you want code to focus on data (like a List(Of Fruits)) rather than controls.  Controls are just how we present a view of the data to the user

Comment: I am doing that, but In order to not have to reference everything twice when it comes to the controls themselves, I'd like to be able to have that specific code easier accessible. @AFriend  suggested passing the list itself. That may work, I have to look into that.

Comment: That is what Tim has shown you in his answer

Comment: @AFriend weird, Tim's answer vanished, had to close the site and reopen it to see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same handler for both ListBoxes and cast the sender:

```
Sub ListBox_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lVegetables.Click, lFruits.Click
    Dim lb = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)
    ListToEditor(lb, lb.SelectedIndex)
End Sub

Private Sub ListToEditor(lb As ListBox, index as Int32)
    tEditor.text = lb.Items(index).ToString()
End Sub
```

The whole code could be simplified to:

```
Sub ListBox_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lVegetables.Click, lFruits.Click
    Dim lb = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)
    If lb.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then tEditor.Text = lb.SelectedItem.ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, this was exactly what I was looking for.